# Changing the shape of a matrix using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

My question is two-fold. I have the following code to do with some matrices.

```
import numpy
tupleList = [(0, 122), (1, 246), (2, 157), (3, 166), (4, 315), (5, 108), (6, 172), (7, 20), (8, 173), (9, 38), (10, 28), (11, 72), (12, 102), (13, 277), (14, 318), (15, 316), (16, 283), (17, 31), (18, 160), (19, 97), (20, 26), (21, 252), (22, 105), (23, 133), (24, 162), (25, 116), (26, 284), (27, 25), (28, 80), (29, 225), (30, 107), (31, 111), (32, 208), (33, 121), (34, 249), (35, 314), (36, 163), (37, 170), (38, 48), (39, 142), (40, 95), (41, 113), (42, 285), (43, 88), (44, 184), (45, 63), (46, 129), (47, 137), (48, 87), (49, 135), (50, 207), (51, 276), (52, 174), (53, 143), (54, 92), (55, 313), (56, 85), (57, 185), (58, 96), (59, 86), (60, 222), (61, 274), (62, 0), (63, 256), (64, 27), (65, 81), (66, 219), (67, 271), (68, 115), (69, 212), (70, 83), (71, 302), (72, 69), (73, 211), (74, 139), (75, 110), (76, 2), (77, 298), (78, 244), (79, 299), (80, 248), (81, 57), (82, 293), (83, 241), (84, 188), (85, 250), (86, 29), (87, 149), (88, 51), (89, 75), (90, 264), (91, 59), (92, 33), (93, 10), (94, 210), (95, 90), (96, 262), (97, 73), (98, 138), (99, 74), (100, 89), (101, 124), (102, 118), (103, 112), (104, 295), (105, 56), (106, 100), (107, 305), (108, 273), (109, 220), (110, 66), (111, 218), (112, 141), (113, 267), (114, 47), (115, 61), (116, 224), (117, 123), (118, 136), (119, 127), (120, 126), (121, 125), (122, 292), (123, 64), (124, 84), (125, 18), (126, 134), (127, 24), (128, 279), (129, 13), (130, 1), (131, 6), (132, 282), (133, 290), (134, 151), (135, 245), (136, 307), (137, 257), (138, 187), (139, 148), (140, 234), (141, 158), (142, 161), (143, 268), (144, 209), (145, 140), (146, 35), (147, 8), (148, 291), (149, 177), (150, 7), (151, 11), (152, 194), (153, 9), (154, 195), (155, 82), (156, 186), (157, 270), (158, 280), (159, 104), (160, 101), (161, 98), (162, 50), (163, 99), (164, 216), (165, 117), (166, 215), (167, 62), (168, 297), (169, 39), (170, 176), (171, 150), (172, 60), (173, 197), (174, 183), (175, 237), (176, 192), (177, 189), (178, 23), (179, 303), (180, 272), (181, 213), (182, 37), (183, 217), (184, 236), (185, 147), (186, 199), (187, 41), (188, 55), (189, 175), (190, 67), (191, 193), (192, 46), (193, 196), (194, 278), (195, 251), (196, 204), (197, 53), (198, 258), (199, 179), (200, 247), (201, 260), (202, 238), (203, 159), (204, 114), (205, 223), (206, 308), (207, 243), (208, 45), (209, 52), (210, 269), (211, 152), (212, 154), (213, 146), (214, 198), (215, 190), (216, 203), (217, 319), (218, 242), (219, 294), (220, 130), (221, 68), (222, 311), (223, 155), (224, 36), (225, 281), (226, 17), (227, 310), (228, 296), (229, 12), (230, 153), (231, 120), (232, 4), (233, 65), (234, 180), (235, 202), (236, 226), (237, 54), (238, 289), (239, 254), (240, 109), (241, 144), (242, 205), (243, 132), (244, 240), (245, 178), (246, 263), (247, 232), (248, 58), (249, 214), (250, 275), (251, 306), (252, 309), (253, 181), (254, 231), (255, 103), (256, 227), (257, 165), (258, 286), (259, 171), (260, 32), (261, 70), (262, 312), (263, 301), (264, 287), (265, 288), (266, 206), (267, 230), (268, 16), (269, 91), (270, 182), (271, 43), (272, 191), (273, 228), (274, 317), (275, 265), (276, 145), (277, 239), (278, 259), (279, 167), (280, 34), (281, 106), (282, 131), (283, 76), (284, 266), (285, 49), (286, 300), (287, 201), (288, 93), (289, 44), (290, 42), (291, 40), (292, 3), (293, 229), (294, 304), (295, 14), (296, 94), (297, 261), (298, 221), (299, 168), (300, 255), (301, 156), (302, 233), (303, 253), (304, 77), (305, 235), (306, 79), (307, 15), (308, 19), (309, 119), (310, 78), (311, 200), (312, 5), (313, 169), (314, 128), (315, 21), (316, 22), (317, 164), (318, 30), (319, 71)]
var = 320
def binaryMatrix(list):
    size = len(list)
    matrix = numpy.zeros((size,size))
    for tuple in list:
        matrix[tuple[0],tuple[1]] = 1
    #for row in matrix:
    #    print sum(row)
    #    if sum(row) > 1:
    #        print "Incorrect"
    #        break
    #print matrix
return matrix


matrix = binaryMatrix(tupleList)
matrix = numpy.asarray(matrix,int)
newMatrix = numpy.eye(var)
#print newMatrix
print numpy.shape(newMatrix)
newMatrix = newMatrix[matrix]
print newMatrix
print numpy.shape(newMatrix)
```

The function takes a list of tuples and constructs a square binary matrix, where the entry at the location of each tuple is 1, and every other element is 0. The commented out code is simply to make sure that all rows sum to 1, which they do, so it's a valid binary matrix.

The problem I'm having is at this line: newMatrix = newMatrix[matrix]
when printing the shape after that, I'm getting that it's dimensions are 320*320*320; but what I'm looking for is 320*320.

Could someone explain to me A) Why this is happening, and B) How to reshape 'newMatrix' to be 320 by 320?

Comment: `print( numpy.shape(newMatrix) )` before you do `newMatrix = newMatrix[matrix ] gives (320, 320) ... Hmmm ... What do want you accomplish with `newMatrix = newMatrix[matrix ]` ? newMatrix has already the shape you want because numpy.eye(var) created it that way.

Comment: So the answer is A) This is happening because the code you use does exactly this B) There is no need to reshape newMatrix to 320x320 because it is already shaped that way.

Comment: What's the purpose of `newMatrix[matrix]`?  Indexing with a matrix is tricky.  Practice with small arrays first.

Comment: As constructed `matrix` is 2d integer with 0/1 values.  That's not the same as boolean, with True/False values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code:

```
print( "numpy.eye(320) gives a matrix of shape:" , numpy.eye(320).shape )
```

gives:

```
numpy.eye(320) gives a matrix of shape: (320, 320)
```

This answers part B of your question. There is no need to reshape `newMatrix` because it is already (320, 320) .

So let's go over to part A of your question "Why is this happening that `newMatrix` after `newMatrix = newMatrix[matrix]` becomes 320x320x320 ?

The answer is: because using `newMatrix[matrix]` does exactly what it should do, create a 320x320x320 matrix.

Comment: You turned out to be entirely correct - as it turns out the code I was writing was totally wrong for the aim I wanted to achieve. The binary matrix was actually all I needed, and everything I was doing after that was superfluous.

Thanks for the help, regardless! I will mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question A), I suggest that you read [this (Index arrays)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays)

The use of index arrays can sometimes be non-intuitive, so see for instance the following matrix indexing:

```
import numpy as np

newMatrix = np.eye(2)
print newMatrix[0]
```

we get :

```
[ 1.  0.]
```

The result is the first element of the array along the largest dimension (dim 2), i.e. the first row of the matrix. Now, if we index using an array (notice the added brackets):

```
import numpy as np
newMatrix = np.eye(2)
print newMatrix[[0]]
```

we get :

```
[[ 1.  0.]]
```

This time, the result is still the first row of the matrix, but given in an array with a similar shape to the indexing array. From the page linked to above :

> Generally speaking, what is returned when index arrays are used is an
>   array with the same shape as the index array, but with the type and
>   values of the array being indexed.

So I imagine numpy replacing the scalars in the indexing array with the matrix element given by that index scalar. If we try indexing with a matrix :

```
import numpy as np

indx = np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])
newMatrix = np.eye(2)
print newMatrix[indx]
```

gives us :

```
[[[ 0.  1.]
  [ 1.  0.]]

 [[ 1.  0.]
  [ 0.  1.]]]
```

because every scalar in the indexing array is replaced by the corresponding row of the matrix in the result, thus also increasing the dimension of the result by 1 compared to the indexing array.

In your example, your final `newMatrix` is similar to your `matrix`, but where every scalar in `matrix` is replaced by either row 0 or 1 of your initial `newMatrix`, thus giving the final shape of your result.

This is probably not what you want, though. It might be interesting to have a look at boolean indexing. I suggest reading [this (Boolean or “mask” index arrays)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

You can save yourself a lot of work if you let NumPy do the indexing:

```
# Wrap indices in numpy array
idxarray = numpy.array(tupleList)

# Allocate zeros
data = numpy.zeros((320, 320))

# Set positions in `tupleList` to `1`
data[idxarray[:, 0], idxarray[:, 1]] = 1

# Make sure we only have one `1` per row
print numpy.all(numpy.sum(data, axis=0) <= 1)  # True

# Make sure our shape is correct
print data.shape  # (320, 320)
```

Comment: But his problem comes after creating this nxn array.

Answer (score 0):

Let's experiment with small 3x3 arrays:

```
In [25]: mask = np.array([[1,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0]])
In [26]: mask
Out[26]: 
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0]])
In [27]: arr = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
In [28]: arr
Out[28]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

Using `mask` as you do produces a (3,3,3) array:

```
In [29]: arr[mask]
Out[29]: 
array([[[3, 4, 5],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [0, 1, 2]]])
```

Changing `mask` to boolean, produces a 1d array, selecting values from `arr` that match the location of `True` in `mask`:

```
In [30]: arr[mask.astype(bool)]
Out[30]: array([0, 5, 7])
```

Another option is multiplication, which will zero out values, returning a (3,3):

```
In [31]: arr*mask
Out[31]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 5],
       [0, 7, 0]])
```

Or something similar with masked array:

```
In [37]: np.ma.MaskedArray(arr,~mask.astype(bool))
Out[37]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[0 -- --]
 [-- -- 5]
 [-- 7 --]],
             mask =
 [[False  True  True]
 [ True  True False]
 [ True False  True]],
       fill_value = 999999)
```